# container-fluid leaving blank space

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to use a full width div, so added container-fluid class which leaves blank space on left and right. I solved it using negative margin left and right. But the  problem is the negative margin afftects bootstrap responsive nature. When I resize the left side contents are hidden and there is a horizontal scrollbar on resizing.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row" style="background-color:gainsboro">
 <div class="col-md-10">
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you show more of your code? The code you have provided doesn't recreate the problem. https://jsfiddle.net/txo2b4pj/

Comment: This is my code here.. I only face problem on resize https://jsfiddle.net/txo2b4pj/1/         I want to have achieve this: http://www.ichangemycity.com/about-us

Comment: So essentially you don't want to have the little bit of padding `container-fluid` provides?

Comment: yes. I want to achieve this: http://www.ichangemycity.com/about-us . When I add container fluid the content is at proper place but just I want to extend that grey background

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're having with the padding is the result of the classes you are calling. Both the `col-md` series and `container-fluid` come out of the box with

```
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
```

For a padding of `30px` on each side combined. The simplest way to fix your content being clipped is by creating your own class to include

```
.container-margin {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}
```

The `row` class with take care of `-15px`, and the above will take care of the rest. This way if you ever chose to use `container-fluid` again, you wouldn't get the same result for all of them.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/u3z9nkvf/4/) is a fiddle with your code updated.

Comment: Thanks .. But see this: on resizing this happens http://snag.gy/mFeDZ.jpg Bit of content is hidden

Comment: Does that only happen on a smaller resolution, or all the time?

Comment: Okay check the fiddle link - I updated the code to be more responsive to your needs. If the margin for the `max-width: 479px` is a bit off, don't be shy to play with it until you get the desired result.

Answer (score 5):

All I did in this scenario is apply the following styling and no padding or horizontal scrollbars, works on small devices too.

```css
.container-fluid{
  padding-left: 0rem;
  padding-right: 0rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add `overflow:hidden` to your container.

Comment: I did but on resize the hoeizontal scrollbar appears and the half content is not visible because of negative margins

Comment: try to not use negative margins on your container instead override the container-fluid.

container-fluid{
  padding-left:0;
  padding-right:0;
}

Comment: but will it affect my rest of the pages?

Comment: if you will use the container-fluid class again.
so better to put another class on your main container.


<div class="container-fluid wrapper">
</div>


then in your css.


.wrapper{
 padding-left:0;
 padding-right:0;
}

Comment: I did but still there is a blank space on left and right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bootstrap utilities class `m-0` to remove unwanted margins.

```
<div class="container-fluid m-0">
    <div class="row" style="background-color:gainsboro">
        <div class="col-md-10">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to mimic http://www.ichangemycity.com/about-us and using Bootstraps "content centered" layout.

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/osserpse/9L3g1ezw/4/

1. Keep `.container` to make the text content to center on the view
2. Add a new class, `my-full-width`to `<div class="col-md-10 my-full-width>` where you want the background to span full width. As far as I know it's not possible to change/add Bootstraps `.row`or `.col-*` classes and retain control over their width and responsive behavior AND to create a background on full width of the *viewport*. (Side note: it's a best practice to scope custom classes in Bootstrap projects so is super simple to spot which classes are Bootstrap native and which are project specific; in my example I use `.my-*`

**CSS:**

```
.my-full-width::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: aliceblue;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -100%;
  left: -100%;
  z-index: 0
}
// Add elements and classes here
h1, p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1; //to make elements to render above the background
}
```